# Add columns in wordpress users table

Tags: php, wordpress

i currently have a problem with my admin section. I'd like to add some infos about my users and display these infos in the array.

Here a screenshot : [view of table](http://awesomescreenshot.com/09a11nkd14)

You can see i've added some columns.

When you click on user account the fieds corresponding to these columns are present and filled.
The info is in the sql base too. But nothing displayed in the table :(

Comment: Check the query which returns the user data. May be those columns value are not coming there.

Comment: Don't mess with the default db structure. Zekth advice bellow is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the User Meta to be Wordpress friendly
Here is how to add a user meta : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta

But if you prefer you can use a meta manager like this one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-meta-manager/

Comment: then approve the answer :)